# Is a website of embedded youtube videos (including screenshots and written descriptions) copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright, internet, youtube

I'm thinking to create a website to curate a list of top youtube recipe videos...

- I would embed the youtube video itself (properly according to youtube's own guidelines).
- I would list out the ingredients and write steps to describe the video in text/bullet list format.
- I would provide links to the creator's youtube channel and credit the recipe to them.

I presume the first bullet point would be ok legally, since youtube offers an embed function (and offers creators the option to disable it).

The list of ingredients I've seen elsewhere described as public domain. But a summary of the steps taken, a "paraphrased transcription" of sorts, is that copyright infringement? What about screenshots from the video?

I suppose my question is where does the line get crossed?